# Selección de rangos de fechas en DataFrames

Tags: pandas

Dispongo del siguiente DataFrame
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La siguiente sentencia debería fitrarme correctamente los valores entre dos fechas.

```
# filtrando sólo del 2018-07-26 al 2018-08-02
df_selec['2018-07-26':'2018-08-02']
```

Sin embargo, me devuelve

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [cierres, Retornos, Retornos_acum, var_diaria, rend_diario, tend, prod_mov, pronostico, MA7, MA30, MA90, MA120]
Index: []
```

Esta otra forma de filtrar

```
# Seleccionar entre dos fechas del índice 
df_selec[(df_selec['Date'] > '2018-07-30') & (df_selec['Date'] < '2018-08-02')]
```

Me devuelve

```
KeyError: 'Date'
```

Si ahora hacemos lo mismo con un DataFrame conseguido de Yahoo, la selección se realiza correctamente

```
# Creando una serie de tiempo de las acciones de WFT desde yahoo finance
wft = web.DataReader("WFT", 'yahoo', '2000-1-1', '2018-8-30')
# filtrando sólo del 2016-02-04 al 2016-02-18
wft['2016-02-04':'2016-02-18']
```

¿Dónde está mi error? ¿Qué es lo que no entieno?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando las fechas son el índice del df, podemos seleccionar cotizaciones de varias maneras.
Opción 1.

```
# Enero de 2018
df_analisis = df_selec.loc["2018-1"]
df_analisis[:3]
```

Opción 1

```
# Seleccionar cotizaciones en un período de tiempo
df_selec.loc[ '2018-01-02' : '2018-01-29' ]
```

Opción 3.

```
# Seleccionar cotizaciones en un período de tiempo
df_selec.loc[pd.Timestamp('2017-01-02'):pd.Timestamp('2017-01-31')]
```

Opción 4.

```
# Se seleccionan los datos desde el 2013-04-14 a 2013-04-18
# Se crean las fechas con la librería datetime
fecha_1 = dt.datetime(2017, 1, 2)
fecha_2 = dt.datetime(2018, 10, 11)

# Filtro por fecha
df_analisis = df_selec.loc[fecha_1: fecha_2]
df_analisis[:3]
```

Opción 5.

```
    # Seleccionar un rango de fechas
    start = "2017-01-02"
    end = dt.datetime.now()
    df_analisis = df_selec[start:end]
    df_analisis[:3]
Cuando las fechas estan en una columna.
Opción 1.
aux = df_selec[(df_selec['Date'] > "2017-01-01") & (df_selec['Date'] <= "2018-10-11")]
df_analisis = aux.set_index("Date")
df_analisis [:3]
```

Comment: +1. Te faltó el caso en que las fechas están en una columna, pero de tipo `datetime` en vez de cadena. En ese caso puedes acceder a  `df.Date.dt.year`, `df.Date.dt.month`, etc.  para acceder a los campos individuales del datetime.

Comment: No conozco esta opción. Intento

Comment: No conozco esta opción. Intento    df_R4.reset_index()
df_R4.Index.dt.year y me devuelve "
AttributeError: 'AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt''". ¿Podias desarrollárnosla?. Gracias por la sugerencia

Comment: Si `df` tiene una columna llamada por ejemplo `fecha` cuyos elementos son de tipo `datetime`, si haces `df.fecha.dt.year` te genera una serie que contiene sólo el número del año. Puedes usarlo para filtrar en el `df` original. Por ejemplo: `df[df.fecha.dt.month == 2]` se queda sólo con las filas de `df` correspondientes a febrero. En tu caso te falla porque aparentemente la columna `Index` no es de tipo `datetime`, sino de tipo `DatetimeIndex`. No sé cómo llegaste a esa situación...

Comment: El df lo he creado importanto de ficheros .csv, exportados de una Web de Internet, utilizando  "...        df_temp = pd.read_csv("./Ficheros_csv/{}.csv".format(symbol),index_col = "Date",
                              decimal  =",", parse_dates = True, usecols = ["Date", "Close"], na_values = ["nan"], sep='\t')
..."  ¿Se puede conseguir en la importación que Date coja el tipo "datetime" directamente?.

Comment: He probado añadiendo "...dtype ="datetime", .." y devuelve "data type "datetime" not understood"

Comment: No, el tipo "datetime" no se "fuerza" así, es el que resutla de usar `pandas.to_datetime(serie)`, siendo los elementos de la serie algo que pandas pueda interpretar como una fecha-hora. Pueden ser cadenas, pueden ser _timestamps_ unix, pueden ser seguramente incluso una lista de `DatetimeIndex`. No sé si se puede forzar que haga esa conversión automáticamente al leer del .csv. Quizás si haces `from datetime import datetime`  y usas `dtype=datetime`?

Comment: He comprobado que, al resetear el índice del df, crea la columna "index", y que es del tipo "index            881 non-null datetime64[ns]". Ahora, la sentenciaa "df1.index.dt.year" me devuelve el error "AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt'"

Comment: Pero eso debe de ser porque se lía, ya que la columna que crea se llama `index`, pero `df.index` no se refiere a esa columna, sino al índice del dataframe. Quizás puedas acceder a la columna por `df["index"]`

Comment: Efectivamente. He renombrado la columna "df1 = df1.rename(columns={'index': 'Date'})" y entonces el resultado de "df1.Date.dt.year" es lo que tu indicas, en la columna "Date, solamnete aparce el año. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Opción para filtrar las filas cuyos índices en el dataframe se encuentran en una lista:   selection = df[df.index.isin(lista)]

Comment: Opción para filtrar las filas que, en la columna "Date" tienen las fechas incluidas en una lista: selection = df[df.Date.isin(lista)]